# execute javascript from inside a div retrieved via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the below code and I am looking to access a bunch of dynamic forms inside the div. How can this be done if I move the forms on to the same page as the javascript. It works fine but when the page is requested via ajax into the div the forms don't access the javascript

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('form.frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',                       
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                      success: function(data) {
                           if(data.status == '1')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            } 
                           if(data.status == '2')
                            {
                                $('#info').addClass('alert alert-danger no-border').html(data.message);
                            }                               
                        }  
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
    function webapp_get_customers(xy){
       $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/limitless/SWAG',
       dataType: 'html'
      }).done(function( data ) {
      $('#webapp_get_customers').html(data);
      });
    }   
    webapp_get_customers();
    </script>       


    <div id='webapp_get_customers'></div>
```

Comment: You should always put your script in an onload event listener.

Comment: I can see the content in the div I want to be able to submit the form and it still validate

Comment: You have a few ajax requests here... which ones are returning the dead scripts? Also, is the data being returned *only* the dead scripts or is it html with javascript sprinkled in?

Comment: The scrip in question is the webapp_get_customers it just retrieves pure html content and a few forms and the script form.form details checks the forms and submits them if the forms are submitted

Comment: So basically you load in new forms to your page with ajax but when you click submit on these new forms, they don't submit?

Comment: That's is correct nick

Answer (score 0):

When you have something like this, you basically attach an event listener to every `form.frm_details` in the DOM when the page first loads:

```
$('form.frm_details').on('submit', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

The problem is when you load in new `form.frm_details` elements, they won't have this event attached to them. A way to solve this problem is to give a parent element the event handler, like the `body` for example. Consider something like this:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form.frm_details', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: any chance on getting an example of how to attach this to the dom

Comment: @Nathan What do you mean exactly? Did you try my solution?

Comment: I'm just not sure where I need to add your answer

Comment: any chance of seeing how i could implement this

Comment: I don't know which part you're confused about; in my example I show what code to replace.

Comment: Oh I get it sorry so I should replace part of my code with your code

Comment: @Nathan Basically - do you understand the part about attaching event listeners and why the code you have right now isn't working properly?

Comment: i understand the code is not working because it cannot access the content inside the dom so its not listening for the submit button inside the dom